# when rendering SRC attributes with PHP, should parameters be delimited with "&" or "&amp;"

Tags: php, html, encoding

If I use PHP to create some iframe content, why should parameters within the `src` attribute be delimited with `&amp;`? When I use `&`, and view source in Chrome, I see they are rendered as `&amp;`, which makes it impossible to copy paste into the location bar of the browser, though when I click the link (Chrome makes the src attribute a link), I am taken to the url successfully.

When viewing the source in Firefox, however, it is still displayed as `&`, but it is bright red and when it is hovered over, I get the tooltip `'"&" did not start a character reference. ("&" should probably have been escaped as "&amp;".)'`

Why is it "probably"? Wouldn't using `&amp;` make copy/pasting likewise impossible? Which should I use and why?

Comment: You need to understand what escaping means.  Whenever you insert text (including URLs) in HTML (including attributes), you need to HTML-escape it.

Comment: If it’s going in a HTML attribute, then it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @SLaks That will make the HTML render correctly. But if a user views the source or inspects the element, won't it be impossible to copy paste it into the location bar?

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not the primary purpose of HTML source code.

Comment: If you *do* need to go into the HTML source, you can right click->"Copy Link Location"